# How to process Boolean NULL values when loading data from S3 to RedShift?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm parsing boolean values to strings so that they will be saved to `csv` files among other data and loaded to S3. The files are then getting loaded to RedShift. I want boolean columns to contain true/false as well as null values (as NULL, N/A or just an empty cell).

After reading the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Boolean_type.html) about Boolean values in RedShift I decided to store null values as NULL. According to the doc `NULL` is a valid boolean value. Here is how I parsed booleans to strings:

```
  private def parseBooleans(value: Option[Boolean]): String = {
    value match {
      case Some(true) => "true"
      case Some(false) => "false"
      case None => "NULL"
    }
  }
```

However I'm getting an `1210 Unknown boolean format` error. I've also tried to pass "N/A" but it's also not working.

How is it possible to pass null values to boolean columns in a RedShift table?

Comment: Just `null` maybe?

Comment: @Dima unfortunately it results with the same error

Comment: I suspect the scala code is passing the literal string "NULL" rather than an actual null, which is the cause of the error. Maybe you need to use `scala.Null` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`NULL AS`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-null-as) option to `COPY` command. Or use it's default value `'\N'`.

```
COPY mytable
FROM 's3://path' 
NULL AS 'NULL'
```